# Macbook Air cannot connect to the Time Capsule's shared disk

Tags: macos, mac, time-capsule

My 802.11ac Time Capsule is sharing Wifi and disk to several computers at home. My Raspberry Pi can mount and list files correctly on the Time Capsule's shared disk. However, my MacBook Air could not connect to the Time Capsule since yesterday. Tried rebooted a few times, it still show the following error:

[image]

Clicking the "Connecting As..." button does not activate anything ...

[image]

How can I troubleshoot the problem?

Answer (score 1):

[FYI, That's not the icon for the 2013 Time Capsule, which is the tall 802.11ac model. The last model of Time Capsule that was wide and flat like that was the 2011 model, also known as "Time Capsule (4th generation)", which was still being sold until replaced by the 802.11ac tower in June 2013. Did you misspeak or is Mac OS X showing you the wrong icon?]

When you said you rebooted, did you reboot the Mac, or the Time Capsule, or both? If you didn't reboot one of those two, try rebooting the one you didn't reboot yet.

Make sure you have the latest firmware on your Time Capsule. If you have the 2011 model, it's v7.6.4. There was a disk sharing related bug that Apple fixed between v7.6.3 and 7.6.4. If you have the 2013 802.11ac tower, you want v7.7.1.

Comment: It's the 802.11ac model, updated question. Rebooted Mac, will reboot the Time Capsule when I return home.